# Building custom widgets like Safari's URL bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, widget

I'm new to Cocoa, and trying to figure out how to build custom widgets (views?). I'm particularly interested in something like Safari's URL bar that acts and looks like a text field, but has buttons, or at least clickable components, at either end.

I've been doing some research – mostly looking at Hillegass's book and *Cocoa and Objective-C: Up and Running* from O'Reilly – on custom views and trying to build things with NSCells. It's still all pretty fuzzy to me... Am I on the right track with this line of research?

Can anyone give a quick break down of what widgets the URL bar is *probably* made up of?

Can anyone give me an idea of how this is done or, failing that, point me to some resources that would be particularly good at explaining this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You want to subclass NSView. From there you can either implement the -(void)drawRect method to do your own custom drawing, or you can add subviews, or both.

```
//add some subviews
NSTextField * textField = [[[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds] autorelease];
[self addSubview:textField];


NSButton * button = ...
[self addSubview:button];
```

You can also use the Interface Builder (now built in to XCode 4) to design the widget, and then hook up the parts with code.